# Gazebo 1.3 plugin + ROS incompatibility?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After writing some code to pull LIDAR data and induce simple movement control for gazebo-1.2, the update rendered these problematic.

I've re-installed gazebo, drcsim, ros-fuerte, and the boost 1.46 libraries in an attempt to find the problem, but I can still deterministically crash gazebo1.3 by following these steps:

```
**. /usr/share/drcsim-1.1/setup.sh
roslaunch drc_robot_utils drc_robot.launch
rosrun pr2_teleop teleop_pr2_keyboard**
```

Pressing a movement key exits gazebo without any thrown errors.

Attaching to the laserScan publisher in Rviz induces an exit with the following error as well:

**Exception [MultiRayShape.cc:113] index[0] out of range[0-8742677509569]**

---

Running roswtf gives the following output, but everything seems to be functional and happy in rxgraph.

```
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/robot_state_publisher] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/drc_robot_controller_spawner] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/pr2_mechanism_diagnostics] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/fake_joint_calibration] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/gazebo] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/tf2_buffer_server] raised an error:
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /gazebo->/robot_state_publisher (/clock)
 * /fake_joint_calibration->/drc_robot_controller_spawner (/calibrated)
 * /gazebo->/drc_robot_controller_spawner (/clock)
 * /drc_robot_controller_spawner->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /gazebo->/pr2_mechanism_diagnostics (/clock)
 * /tf2_buffer_server->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /gazebo->/robot_state_publisher (/joint_states)
 * /gazebo->/tf2_buffer_server (/clock)
 * /gazebo->/pr2_mechanism_diagnostics (/mechanism_statistics)
 * /pr2_mechanism_diagnostics->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /gazebo->/gazebo (/clock)
 * /gazebo->/rosout (/clock)
 * /robot_state_publisher->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /gazebo->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /robot_state_publisher->/tf2_buffer_server (/tf)
```

If anyone has a better idea than me with regards to what might be the problems in communications between ros and Gazebo, or what I could do to find out the problems, I would appreciate them very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/490/gazebo-1.3-plugin-+-ros-incompatibility?/) by [klowrey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/113/klowrey/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I suspect that this problem arose from a mismatched set of packages.

I'm unable to reproduce the behavior that you describe with gazebo 1.5.0 and drcsim 2.2.0.  Do you still see the problem if you update?

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0